# How to implement "last command" function in a console based python program

Tags: python, windows

So I am working on a console based python(python3 actually) program where I use `input(">")`to get the command from user.

Now I want to implement the "last command" function in my program - when users press the up arrow on the keyboard they can see their last command.

After some research I found I can use curses lib to implement this but there are two problems.

1. Curses are not available on Windows.
2. The other parts of my program use `print()` to do the output. I don't want to rewrite them with curses.

So are there any others ways to implement the "last command" function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In new versions of python exists nice modile [readline](http://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) for handling user input, and [rlcompleter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/rlcompleter.html) for autocomplete purposes. But I think on Windows it will require installation of readline lib anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do, is to apply some sort of shell history functionality: every command issued by the user would be placed in a list, and then you'd implement a special call (command of your console), let's say 'history' that would print out the list for the user in order as it was being filled in, with increasing number to next to every command. Then, another call (again a special command of your console), let's say '!!' (but really coult be anything, like 'repeat') and a number of the command you want to repeat would fetch the command from the list and execute it without retyping: typing '!! 34' would execute again the command number 34 that can be 'something -a very -b long -c with -d very -e large -f number -g of -h arguments -666'.

I am aware its not exactly the same thing that you wanted, but it is very easy to implement quickly, and provides the command repetition functionality you're after, and should be decent replacement until you figure out how to do it the way you want ;)

Comment: The readline module mentioned by @cleg is great on Unix platform and you've proposed a good workaround on Windows. Thank you.

Comment: If that sounds like a solution, then vote it :) By the way, one thing you have to think about when implementing it, is checking if typed command doesnt start with !!, and if does, then to store only actual repeated command (after fetching it from the list) because otherwise you might get into some unexpected loops.